# How to close a specific socket in the same process programmatically on Android

Tags: android, linux, sockets

Our Android application is using some 3rd party SDK library (native CPP) which is NOT open source.

We found that sometimes the library will not correctly close some udp socket as supposed.

So I want to manually close the socket. The first idea of how to do it is:

1. iterate /proc/net/udp directory, to find the target inode by the port number
2. iterate /proc/$PID/fd directory, to find the target fd number by the inode info
3. close the fd in my own code

My question is:

1. is there any better way (like former API or system calls) to find the target fd?
2. will the process crash if I force close the fd?
3. if the process does not crash, will this operation break anything in the process?

Comment: Complain to the vendor.

Comment: Man, this is lot an option for me now. The vendor does not provide good support. Can you just give me some hint target to my question?